# Difference between 2 Quotient Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-group

Consider the rings, $Z_2[x]/(1 + x^2)$ and $ Z_2[x]/(1 + x + x^2)$, despite having different polynomial as divisor, I have been told that -

$$Z_2[x]/(1 + x^2) = \{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$$

and

$$Z_2[x]/(1 + x + x^2)= \{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$$

Then what is the difference between $Z_2[x]/(1 + x^2)$ and $ Z_2[x]/(1 + x + x^2)$?

Comment: In one $x^2=1$ and in the other $x^2=x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, both quotient rings are vector spaces over $Z_2$ of dimension 2, both with bases $\{1,x\}$.

In general, if $K$ is a finite field and $f(x)$ is a polynomial over $K$ of degree $n$, then $K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is a vector space over $K$ of dimension $n$.

The difference above is that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $Z_2$, while $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ is not. So $Z_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ is a field, while $Z_2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is not (it has zero divisors).

Answer (score 1):

This is a notation issue. When you write $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(1 + x^2) = \{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$, that's just an equality of equivalence classes. In addition, on the RHS of the equality, you're missing some relations that hold in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(1 + x^2)$ as the notation $\{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$ alone doesn't tell anything about relations.

The same with $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(1 + x^2) = \{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$. Moreover the equivalence classes in the latter are not the same as the one in the former, because you're modding out be different ideals, so even as sets  $\{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$ and $\{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$ are are basically different. Hence one should use different notation to avoid confusion.

Comment: ""because you're modding out be different ideals, so even as sets  $\{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$ and $\{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$ are are basically different. Hence one should use different notation to avoid confusion."".. yes I know I am modding out by different ideals, but how sets  $\{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$ and $\{0, 1, x, 1 + x\}$ are are basically different?? There is a typo in second paragraph... in the quotient ring in answer,

Comment: The sets are basically different because as sets, they really are $\{0 + I_1, 1 + I_1, x+I_1, 1+x+I_1\}$ and similarly with $I_2$ for the other one, where $I_i$ are the ideals you're modding out by. We use $0$ to stand for the equivalence class of $0 + I_i$, but these are different for different ideals.